# ARM assembly code and SVC numbering

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

In ARM assembly codes I can see something like these...
(especially in shellcodes)

```
svc 0x0090003f
svc 0x001ff3bf
swi 0x0900ff0b
```

I know that 'svc(or swi)' is the 'supervisor call' like 'int 0x80' or 'SYSENTER' from Intel. but, how can I interpret the 'svc' numbers?? where can I get the listing of it's information??  What about thumb 'svc' instruction??

The arm instruction manual doesn't seem to be explaining these...

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have an example or did you make up those numbers?, they look too big or at least one of them.

Comment: I didn't made that up

Comment: These numbers are not CPU-specific; they're OS-specific. In Linux with an OABI convention, it's the syscall number (with EABI, it should be zero). Other OSes might have their own numbering scheme. In the embedded world, ad-hoc conventions are not unheard of. There's no telling without knowing the platform.

Comment: Just because intel x86 systems make/made heavy use of int xxh calls and the arm architecture has support for a similar thing doesnt mean it is 1) a good idea to do it the same way (use this feature) 2) there is a list of standard svc call numbers...there isnt and for the applications you will typically see that might use these calls, many/most dont.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

6.2.8. SVC handlers

An exception handler might have to determine whether the processor was in ARM or Thumb state when the exception occurred.

SVC handlers, especially, might have to read the processor state. This is done by examining the SPSR T-bit. This bit is set for Thumb state and clear for ARM state.

Both ARM and Thumb instruction sets have the SVC instruction. When calling SVCs from Thumb state, you must consider the following:

The instruction address is at lr-2, rather than lr-4.

The instruction itself is 16-bit, and so requires a halfword load, see Figure 6.3.

The SVC number is held in 8 bits instead of the 24 bits in ARM state.

Read more at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0203j/Cacdfeci.html

Comment: I already saw this, but it doesn't explain what the SVC numbers are

Comment: The SVC numbers are entirely arbitrary and an implementation detail of the operating system in use as they relate its services.  Hence no documentation from ARM.

Comment: thumb2 the number is in a different place, it is non-trivial to non-possible to have a generic all mode handler, probably a good idea to define the mode you must be in to call svc/swi and/or dont bother encoding in the instruction but instead in a gpr...

Comment: @old_timer as well the original instruction encoding was conceived when systems didn’t have  smp, L1, L2, and out of order execution.  Examining an instruction stream can be quite lengthy on modern arm systems.

Answer (score 2):

**The SVC value gets stored in the 16-bits low bits of the ESR register**

The [ARMv8 Architecture Reference](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/db/DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf) D12.2.36 "ESR_EL1, Exception Syndrome Register (EL1)" says that if the EC bits are 0b010101 then the ISS field is documented at "ISS encoding for an exception from HVC or SVC instruction execution".

That section then says that the lower 16 bits are `imm16`, which if you look at the SVC definition is the name given to the 16-bit argument.

Finally, the SVC calls you shows on your question are not valid in ARMv8 GNU GAS, because they are larger than 16-bits. For example:

```
SVC 0xABCDE
```

correctly fails to assemble with:

```
Error: immediate value out of range 0 to 65535 at operand 1 -- `svc 0xABCDE
```

**Runnable example**

Here is a minimalistic aarch64 baremetal runnable example that does an SVC and prints out all registers during the handler, including ESR https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/b1bfd46efebabcba4f1ab1cbddf99611550e2dc2#arm-svc-instruction

Answer (score -1):

From 6.2.8. SVC handlers

Whenever any svc/swi is encountered, control will be transferred to the svc handler. in SVC handler these numbers will be used to identify what subroutine needs to be called so these are the index values which will be taken by handler and processed accordingly.

Example 6.11. SVC handler in C function

```
void C_SVC_handler (unsigned number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
        case 0 :                 /* SVC number 0 code */
            ...
            break;
        case 1 :                 /* SVC number 1 code */
            ...
            break;
        ...
        default :                /* Unknown SVC - report error */
    }
}
```

Reference-
6.2.8. SVC handlers