System call numbers, trap handling, and the C library’s role in system calls
While reading the OSTEP book, I had a question.
From the book:

To specify the exact system call, a system-call number is usually assigned to each system call. The user code is thus responsible for placing the desired system-call number in a register or at a specified location on the stack; the OS, when handling the system call inside the trap handler, examines this number, ensures it is valid, and, if it is, executes the corresponding code. This level of indirection serves as a form of protection; user code cannot specify an exact address to jump to, but rather must request a particular service via number.

I’m trying to better understand how system call numbers work within the context of system calls and trap handling. Here’s what I understand so far:

The system call number is used like a key or index in a trap table, allowing the CPU to jump to the correct trap handler.
Inside the trap handler, the operating system validates the system call number.
The C library’s system call API stores the system call number in a register or on the stack before invoking the trap.

Is my understanding accurate? Could someone clarify or provide additional details, especially regarding the role of the C library and the validation step?

The term "Unix" could mean any number of several related but otherwise distinct and separate operating systems, few which have a common implementation. How system calls are handled depends not only on the OS implementation but also on the target hardware.

Thanks to you, it's clear. The specific implementation will depend on different Unix-like operating systems and hardware. I think the book covered the general stuff.

See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24162109/1216776

@stark Thank you. this is good example for clarification.

The author of the "OSTEP" book keeps using this word, "virtualization".  I do not think it means what he thinks it means.

@MikeNakis: Yes, it does. Virtualization does not just mean virtualizing an entire machine at the operating system level. Presenting each user process with its individual appearance of a CPU (it never sees the CPU registers changed by another process, it runs as if it had the CPU to itself without awareness of being time-sliced to share with other processes) is a form of virtualization. There are many forms of virtualization.

@EricPostpischil by this token, every single instance of information hiding would be eligible for being called virtualization. That is preposterous.

@EricPostpischil also, the Wikipedia article that you linked mentions various forms of virtualization, which are all nothing but flavors of the one known meaning of the word, which is emulating an operating environment within another.  There is no mention of time-slicing, or anything related to time-slicing, in that article.  So, it does not support your argument.

@MikeNakis: Do you mean “operating system environment,” not “operating environment”? It is not limited to virtualizing operating system environments. It mentions virtualizing memory, virtualizing file systems, virtualizing networks, virtualizing disks, and more.

@EricPostpischil This is red herring. Yes, it mentions all those, and more, but it does not mention time slicing, or anything similar to time-slicing, so it does not support your initial point.

@MikeNakis: Time-slicing is not the key. The fact that each process has its own view of the machine is. Each process sees only a machine as if were the sole process on the machine. It executes in a virtual environment. It is a user-mode environment, without access to I/O operations and such, so supported by an operating system underneath it, but it is a virtual environment. “Virtualization” by itself is currently often a reference to whole-machine virtualization, but that is merely because of the current trends of the present. It is not the exclusive use of the term, past or present.



The system call number is used like a key or index in a trap table, allowing the CPU to jump to the correct trap handler.


No.
A "trap table" can be found in CPU architectures that support a TRAP N instruction where N is the trap number. In such architectures, the trap table maps trap numbers to addresses of trap handlers. An operating system typically defines one trap number for offering system calls.
Suppose we have a hypothetical CPU which supports multiple trap handlers, and an operating system which uses TRAP 42 for system calls.
The system call number is something you have to set up before invoking the operating system trap. For example:
LOAD R1, system_call_number
TRAP 42

So, the CPU uses that 42 to look up the trap handler in the trap table, and jumps to it. This will be the operating system trap handler. Within that handler, the operating system uses the value of R1 to look up, in another table, (call it the "system call" table,) the address of the system function, and jump to it.
Note that the process is very similar if the CPU supports a parameterless instruction for invoking the operating system:
LOAD R1, system_call_number
SYSCALL

In this case, there is only one handler, and no trap table.  However, it is still possible to make many different system calls, so the mechanism with system call numbers, resolvable via a system call table, is still there.


Inside the trap handler, the operating system validates the system call number.


Uh, sure.  If the system call number does not correspond to an actual valid system function, the operating system will probably do bad things to your process.


The C library’s system call API stores the system call number in a register or on the stack before invoking the trap.


I do not know what you mean by "The C library’s system call API". In any case, anyone interested in invoking system calls must store the system call number somewhere before invoking the operating system. The operating system defines where the number should be stored. It is usually in a register.

Your response to point 1 was exceptionally clear. Thanks to your explanation, I have gained a solid understanding of the concepts of traps and trap tables. I now understand that traps can be used for various purposes beyond system calls, such as handling exceptions, debugging, and other interrupts, and that they are mapped through the trap table.
I greatly appreciate your thorough examples and detailed explanations. Thank you for your invaluable assistance.

Thank you for clarifying my misunderstanding. I now realize that my misconception was based on focusing solely on my own system. On my machine, when I use the open() function, I do not directly handle the system call number, which led me to believe that the C standard library manages storing the system call number in a register or on the stack at the language level.

Your explanation made me aware that this description was specific to my platform and helped me consider the generalized case across various platforms. I greatly appreciate your detailed and insightful examples and explanations. Thank you very much for your invaluable assistance.

Refer to @MikeNakis's answer for most details.  I just want to respond to this point:

The C library’s system call API stores the system call number in a register or on the stack before invoking the trap.

That's a bit fraught.  Perhaps it's just a poor choice of words, but in case there is a genuine misunderstanding here:
The system call design described in your book has nothing directly to do with any userspace libraries.  In principle, any userspace program can request a system call by the appropriate OS-specific version of the mechanism described by your quotation, without resorting to a library function.
However, if your system offers a hosted C implementation, then many of the functions in the C standard library it provides will indeed perform system calls as described.  Additionally, you may be thinking in particular of syscall wrapper functions provided as extensions by some systems' C implementations.  These do little other than providing a convenient interface to a particular system call.  Also, some systems' C standard libraries provide a generic syscall wrapper that requires the caller to specify the syscall number and to provide appropriate argument in the form expected by the raw syscall.  Except possibly for the last, I don't think any of that is well characterized as a "system call API".

First of all, thank you for clearing up a misconception I had. I realize now that my misunderstanding came from thinking only in terms of my own system. On my machine, when I use the open() function, I don’t specify the system call number as an argument, so I assumed that the C standard library was doing some additional work at the language level. Thanks to your explanation, I now have a much clearer understanding of how system calls and system call numbers work in general.
